# Определить что прошло не больше 5 минут mysql

Tags: mysql, дата, время

Подскажите как сделать запрос на определение что прошло время не больше 5 минут?

Есть таблица с полями DATE и TIME.

Я делаю запрос на получение данных, в котором предаю время. В таблице записано время. Мне нужно определить что время, которое я передаю, не больше времени которое в таблице на 5 минут.

Спасибо.

Comment: Для начала объедините дату-время в одно поле, тогда сможете пользоваться `+- interval 5 minute`

Comment: @Mike правильно я понимаю что интервал +- от того времени которое я передам?

Comment: да, если текущее время то можно `now() - interval 5 minute` если другое то его в явном виде задавайте